# Unable to upload a joomla template

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I have installed the latest version of Joomla and  downloaded a Joomla template. I downloaded Xampp on to my localhost and got the Apache and MySQL running on the localhost. When i tried to install the package, i see the below message.

> [1] Warning JInstaller: :Install: Can't find XML setup file.
>
> [2]Error Unable to find install package

Answer (score 0):

If you get the same warning and error when installing other extensions, then maybe it's caused by your Xampp configuration.

As an alternative, you could try unzipping your template package and uploading it to

`your site root / templates` directory

Then use the Joomla Extention Manager Discover from
Extensions → Manage → Discover

More about the discover option:
https://docs.joomla.org/Help38:Extensions_Extension_Manager_Discover

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Open the XML file inside the ZIP and change (twice)
`<install` to `<extension`

Save the file and install it

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to extract the template to (for example) /temp/yourtemplate/ and then use the Joomla Extension Manager -> install from directory (setting the directory, where you extracted the files)